# Error on Gridview RowUpdating event.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that I have programmed by hand. I have all the methods for all the events and everything seems to be working but the RowUpdating Event. I get this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I can't figure out what is happening here. All the controls have values entered. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong??

```
 protected void Gridview1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText =    "update t_sizer_calibration " +
                                 "set " +
                                 "date = @date " +
                                 " time = @time, " +
                                 "name = @name, " +
                                 "lane = @lane, " +
                                 "carriers = @carrier, " +
                                 "rev = @REV, " +
                                 "new_tare = @n_tare, " +
                                 "current_tare = @ctare, " +
                                 "min = @min, " +
                                 "max = @max," +
                                 "sd = @sd, " +
                                 "wai = @wai, " +
                                 "bad_carriers = @badcar, " +
                                 "comments = @comments " + 
                                 "where calibration_id = @calibration_id"; 

            // define parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@calibration_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = glblID.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gtxtDate.Text; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gtxtTime.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Int).Value = glblName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@lane", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(gtxtLane.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@carrier", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(gtxtCarriers.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@REV", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(gtxtREV.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@n_tare", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(gtxtN_Tare.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ctare", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(gtxtC_Tare.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@min", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(gtxtMin.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@max", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(gtxtMax.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sd", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(gtxtSD.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@wai", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(gtxtWAI.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@badcar", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(gtxtBadCarriers.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@comments", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = gtxtComments.Text; 

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = this.sqlConnection1;
            this.sqlConnection1.Open();
            //execute insert statement
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.sqlConnection1.Close();          
            //re-populate grid 
            fill_grid();
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

Here is my rowupdated method too :

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        fill_grid();
        //Reset the edit index.
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: And which line is throwing the error? You can copy and paste the exception's stack track as that would certainly help.

Comment: Are you certain `sqlConnection1` is not null?

Comment: sqlConnection1 is the global connection string for the page. I use it a few times in this page.

Comment: I don't know how to include the exception stack. I don't get detailed errors. This is a custom user control that is in another webpage. It is in a dashboard of this software my company uses. If it were a stand alone page then it would be easier to troubleshoot. My main concern is figuring out if I programmed the event correctly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs_properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the values from the row to which you have bound will be returned to you in the `Keys`, `OldValues`, and `NewValues` properties of the event args.  So you don't need to access control values at all.

I would try something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@calibration_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = e.NewValues["ID"];
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = e.NewValues["date"];
```

... and see if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: They are the controls in the template field that are bound to the columns.

Comment: Assuming I understand you correctly, what I said above does apply.  You need to access the particular instances of the controls in the template that belong to the specific grid view item that raised the event.  You do this by performing an `e.Item.FindControl` for each control.  If you don't do this, the variables are never assigned to and will return a null reference exception (what you received) if you attempt to access their properties.

Comment: Error: GridViewUpdateEventArgs does not contain a definition for "Item" and not extension method ...... are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: I'm sorry:  I was thinking of a different grid event.  I will re-do my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much by the way!! It's closer but I get this error: Message: The parameterized query '(@calibration_id varchar(8000),@comments varchar(8000))update t_' expects the parameter '@calibration_id', which was not supplied.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but is `calibration_id` the name of the primary key? You might have to fetch that from `e.Keys` rather than `e.NewValues`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18125/discussion-between-briskovich-and-ann-l)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to use FindControl to get the new values for your update statement.

Like the following:

```
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            int id = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            TextBox comm = (TextBox)row.FindControl("gtxtComments");
            TextBox date = (TextBox)row.FindControl("gtxtDate"); ....... and so on.
```